# Nodemailer with gmail service account

Tags: gmail-api, nodemailer

I'm implementing a "no-reply" account for sending automated emails. Do I need the access key/refresh token, and if so where can I generate them for a service account?

At the moment I have this:

```
noreply = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: smtpConfig.client_email,
        serviceClient: smtpConfig.client_id,
        privateKey: smtpConfig.private_key,
    }
});
```

Which unfortunately gives me this:

```
{ Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials h81sm3513839itb.18 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you do not need a `refresh token` with a service account and nodemailer will generate the `access key` for you automatically

You cannot only use a service account to send emails for a GSuite account and not a gmail account.

If you have a gmail account you can use [3-legged OAuth2 authentication](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#oauth-3lo)
Or turn on 2FA, generate an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en#generate) and use that as seen [here](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#2-single-connection)

If you ARE using a GSuite account you can use the ServiceAccount but you will have to make sure it has **G Suite Domain-wide Delegation** as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) and then you need to give access to the GSuite Domain as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)